# Call function of parent through props in child

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I want to call a function of a parent component within **another** function of the child (the child's function will call the function of the parent).

I passed the function of the parent to the child. But when the code compiles, I get this error:
`Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions`.

```js
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    ...
    this.someFunction = this.someFunction.bind(this);
  }
  
  // The child should call this function
  someFunction() {
    console.log("Doing something");
  }
  
  render() {
    return() {
      <Child doSomething={this.someFunction}>
    }
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.aChildFunction = this.aChildFunction.bind(this);
  }
  
  aChildFunction() {
    // Here is where I get the error
    this.props.doSomething;
  }
  
  render() {
    return() {
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.aChildFunction}>Click</button>
      </div>
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Read the warning carefully - it expected a *call*, you aren't calling the passed function.

Comment: Wow that was easy and worked. I'm just a bit confused, why it worked with `this.props.doSomething();` instead. Because within another component I accessed the props within the render function directly via `onClick={this.props.aFunctionPassedToChild}` and works. Why is that working? @jonrsharpe

Comment: Because then the machinery behind onClick calls the function, the same way that it calls this.aChildFunction in your example.

Comment: I see! Thanks! Can I somehow mark your answer as the solution? Otherwise I'd chose Flavin's because there it gives me the option to do so.

Comment: You can't accept comments; this is just a typo, and should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed the paranthesis "()" while calling the function.

```js
  aChildFunction() {
    // Call the function to execute
    this.props.doSomething();
  }
```

Comment: @trynalearn please accept the answer if it completely solves your issue, otherwise comment what additional problems you're facing

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish that.

Firstly, you got to call the function as already stated in other answers.

```js
aChildFunction() {
  this.props.doSomething();
}

render() {
  return() {
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.aChildFunction}>Click</button>
    </div>
  }
}
```

You can also pass `doSomething` as a handler directly and skip `aChildFunction`.

```js
render() {
  return() {
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.props.doSomething}>Click</button>
    </div>
  }
}
```

In this case your `doSomething` callback will be called with the `MouseEvent` as an argument, but don't worry if you're not going to use it.